# Displaying user's profile picture dynamically in email template

Tags: apex, callout, httpcalloutmock, visualforce-template, base64

I have a requirement to display user's profile picture dynamically in the email template.

Email template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<c:UserImg />
</messaging:htmlEmailBody >
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Vf component:

```
<apex:component controller="TemplateController" access="global">
    <img src="{!currentUserImgURI}"/>
</apex:component>
```

Controller:

```
public class TemplateController {
    public String currentUserImgURI {public get; public set;}

    public TemplateController() {

    //if(currentUserImgURI !=null)
        User currentUser = [SELECT SmallPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
        currentUserImgURI = getDataUriFromUri(currentUser.SmallPhotoUrl);
    }

    public static String getDataUriFromUri(String url) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        Http binding = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = binding.send(req);
        System.debug('Debug111'+res);
        System.debug('Debug222' +res.getBody());

        Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
                return 'data:'+res.getHeader('Content-Type')+';base64,'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
    }
}
```

I have created these in my sandbox and tried to test the template but there is no picture output in email. When looked at the debug logs, the statement System.debug('Debug111'+res); has blank value. Response seems to be blank. Please help me where I have done wrong?

Comment: Hi, I have a requirement to display user's profile picture dynamically in the email template.

Email template:
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<c:UserImg />
</messaging:htmlEmailBody >
</messaging:emailTemplate>


Vf component:
<apex:component controller="TemplateController" access="global">
    <img src="{!currentUserImgURI}"/>
</apex:component>

Comment: Did you add the url to the allowed external site like [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm)?

Comment: Yes. I did add the URL in remote site settings. There is no issue with connection errors. The only problem is that I am unable to understand why am I getting blank response in http response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to `User.SmallPhotoURL` or `User.LargePhotoURL` needs authentication. In your case this might be a issue.

Instead use `ChatterUsers` class to get the photo URls. There is a variable called `standardEmail`​PhotoUrl is available which is *A temporary URL to the small profile. The URL expires after 30 days and is available to unauthenticated users.*

So you can access this URL and convert it to a blob data. I just modified your class and it is working for me. Don't forget to add the URL is remote site setting.

```
public class TemplateController {
    public String currentUserImgURI {public get; public set;}

    public TemplateController() {
        ConnectApi.Photo ph =  ConnectApi.UserProfiles.getPhoto(null, UserInfo.getUserId());
        System.debug('@@ph.standardEmailPhotoUrl'+ph.standardEmailPhotoUrl);
        currentUserImgURI = getDataUriFromUri(ph.standardEmailPhotoUrl);
        System.debug('@@'+currentUserImgURI);
    }

    public static String getDataUriFromUri(String url) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        Http binding = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = binding.send(req);
        System.debug('Debug111'+res);
        System.debug('Debug222' +res.getBody());

        Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
        return 'data:'+res.getHeader('Content-Type')+';base64,'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: My end point is: https://test.salesforce.com  but I have got this error in template now. https://test.salesforce.com/ncsphoto/ZVq--ftN7j8r7aU1q_HbIZ_efE2VIM1qTuM7d9tyQUR6CIpsecs2n7GFw3. Please try editing your markup to correct the problem. Anything wrong in my remote site settings?

Comment: Create a VF page and add this <img src="{!currentUserImgURI}"/>. Check if you are able to see the image.

Comment: I tested it in vf page and I got this error: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://test.salesforce.com/ncsphoto/ZVcDRmKnq--ftN7j8r7aU1q_HbIZ_efE2VIM1qTuM7d9tyQUR6CIpsecs2n7GFw3 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Comment: I even tried to create all this in my developer org and I received the same error. Error occurred trying to load the template for preview: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://ap1.salesforce.com/img/userprofile/default_profile_45_v2.png?fromEmail=1. Please try editing your markup to correct the problem.  ->https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glbXAAQ This link also shows some one has similar problem but no fix found.

Comment: I tested with an email template. I can see the image in the email preview. You should add only https://ap1.salesforce.com to remote site setting.

Comment: Hi Saroj, Yes it worked but in email it is showing X mark not the full picture. I downloaded picture but still it showed X mark symbol

Comment: Thanks for your help. It might be some outlook issue. I can see the picture in web email now.. :)

Comment: Glad to see it worked.

Comment: Hi..Need help on this. I tried the same but it is not working form me